# Is this a kernel panic or a kernel oops?

Tags: kernel

This is a photo I tried accessing my /var/logs, but I'm unsuccessful. Is this a panic or an oops? It has happen about 3 times in 24 hours. Could it be due to a corrupt media? The Ubuntu server install is about 24 hours old and this computer is fairly old 2005 AMD Athlon 64 - 4600. It's running great besides this small hiccup.

Kernel 3.0.25 - Upgraded using apt-get dist-upgrade immediately after install. So I don't know if its a kernel issue or perhaps something else.

Here is the log that I took a photo of.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a panic (look at 720139), and because all panics are oops, it is also an oop.

It looks more like a BUG in a driver than faulty hardware, that *scheduling while atomic* message usually is caused by a programing error, not hardware faults.